# How to delete an object by it's class attributes, and return it's object value?

Tags: c++

I created an array of objects in main() used for a shopping list(groceryitems is the class name)

> groceryitems items[10];

So basically while adding items to this list, it's assigned a code by the user as it's attribute.

I would like to remove an object (from the array) by inputting it's code(the attribute), so let's say item 3 has a code of 10000, how do I remove this item with the user inputting 10000?

How do I search which object has a code attribute of 10000 and then return it's value to delete it from the main? Or can I delete it with a function from within the class?

Comment: What do you mean by "delete"? You have a statically sized array of objects, you cannot remove items from that

Comment: Use a `std::vector` to add and remove items dynamically.

Comment: Sounds more like a job for `std::map`

Comment: As in remove data from that part.

Answer (score 1):

In C++ an array has a static size. You can't resize arrays. You can't add or remove objects. For your use case I recommend [`std::unordered_map`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/unordered_map). If the code is unique you can store the objects by their code. You can also find and delete them by code.

Alternatively you can use [`std::vector`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector), search with [`std::find`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/find) and delete objects with [`std::vector::erase`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/erase)